# The meaning of "you equal parts"

Tags: meaning

In the article "[What to Do When You’re Addicted to Coffee, but It Hurts Your Stomach](https://www.myrecipes.com/extracrispy/coffee-hurts-help-me)" the author suggests that

> "if the thought of giving up your coffee makes you equal parts drained and distraught, there’s always the trusty antacid. Just make sure your coffee is worth it"

What is the meaning of "you equal parts"? Based on my research, "equal parts" means

> "Division resulting in identical parts. Having the same portion, division, piece, or segment of a whole".

Thanks.

Comment: "..makes you / equal parts / drained and distraught." It makes you [feel] drained and distraught, in equal parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means "makes you [feel] equal parts drained and distraught".

Coffee provides caffeine, and the author is saying that it may be such a part of you that the thought of you without it makes you feel like you lack energy (drained) and makes you upset and agitated (distraught).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations!